# Can you unit test a void method which doesnt have return type?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, methods, void

I have this void method which I would like to unit test but unfortunately, I don't have much experience in this.

```
public void findOccuranceMethod()
{
    string str = "The Haunting of Hill House!";
    Console.WriteLine("String: " + str);
    string occurString = "o";
    string replaceString = "MDDS";

    var array = str.Split(new[] { occurString }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var count = array.Length - 1;
    string result = string.Join(replaceString, array);

    Console.WriteLine("String after replacing a character: " + result);
    Console.WriteLine("Number of replaces made: " + count);
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Here is the TestClass where i am trying to test but it keeps loading when i run it:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void findOccuranceMethodTest()
{
    // Arrange
    string expected = "The Haunting MDDSf Hill HMDDSuse!";

    // Act
    var result = new findOccurance();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense on its own, and is not compilable as is. Can you add enough to it to make it actually compile and demonstrate the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: if the target has dependencies you can assert the expected behavior

Comment: I suggest you review the suggestions from your previous question. Then update it properly so that it can be reopened. You could have at least deleted that one before asking the same question again.

Comment: @Nkosi I have edited the previous one but nothing changed so I decided to repost it. Can you unmark as duplicate, I will delete the previous one now.

Comment: @Nkosi now I cant even delete because you marked it

Comment: @BMX reopened it.

Comment: @cHao this basically takes a string and changes the occurrences of 'o' with 'MDDS'. Now I would like to unit test but I have no idea how to do it due to its void type which doesnt return anything.

Comment: @BMX: I don't see where it takes a string. You never pass one in.

Comment: This will deadlock because of the Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @Nkosi can you please explain in more words what do you mean by your suggestion? or can you take an example and post as an answer?

Comment: @cHao it is declared as str , check below I am using it as str.split...

Comment: @BMX: It's declared as `str` *within the function*. But it's never given a value from outside the function, ie: no string is ever passed in. Outside the function, nothing gets to care about your local variables.

Comment: @cHao ok so you are saying I need to declare those outside the function right?

Comment: What would you want to test in this method? There's no real logic here - only executing the statements one by one. No input, no output... I wouldn't bother testing this at all.

Comment: @BMX: I'm saying those should be parameters. Ideally, your output writer should be a parameter as well. Then you can more easily check what the code did.

Comment: Or, yeah, don't test at all. It might not be worth the effort to make it testable if this is all it will ever do.

Comment: I agree Zolar, there´s not much to test here as your method doesn´t do much, just writing sometjng to console, which you can´t really test as it´s a static dependency. Apart from this even a void method has some kind of an outcome - e.g. a file that it creates or a property it sets - for which you can test against.

Comment: @cHao what I want to test is if the output is the same as I specify in the Arrange.

Comment: @BMX: No, that's not what you want to test, because if it were, you'd be trying to look for the "String after replacing a character: " as well. No, what you want to test is whether your string-replace does what it's supposed to -- cause if it does, then you already know the output will be correct. So take the string-replace code out and make it its own function, ideally taking the relevant strings as parameters, and returning the string with all the replacements done. That function will be trivial to unit test, and you don't even need to change your existing function's signature.

Comment: @cHao why not just test the output if its the same that I specify in a string? I mean that should be simplier right?

Comment: @BMX: No, it's not simpler. Not only have you written to the console (which you could consider as exporting that data to somewhere else), but you've added a bunch of filler text that you'd have to sift through as well. If you can test the result of your calculations, you don't have to try and parse anything.

Comment: Usually you don´t want to test UI - the **presentation-layer**, in your case the console - but if the UI gets the right **data**, which is the **business-layer**. Having said this you should devide your method into two, one that performs the actual logic and creates your string, and the other that **presents** it within the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code properly refactored for testability

The proper way of coding and unit-testing such a logic would be:

```cs
public class SomeProductionClass 
{
    public string findOccuranceMethod(string str) 
    {
        string occurString = "o";
        string replaceString = "MDDS";
        var array = str.Split(new[] { occurString }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string result = string.Join(replaceString, array);

        return result;
    }
}

[TestMethod()]
public void findOccuranceMethodTest()
{
    // Arrange
    string expected = "The Haunting MDDSf Hill HMDDSuse!";
    var productionClass = new SomeProductionClass();

    // Act
    var result = productionClass.findOccuranceMethod("The Haunting of Hill House!");

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

### How to test the original code

If for some reason you cannot control the production code, there are two options:

- replace `Console` with an abstraction
- reassign standard input/output to a custom stream: this is the least preferred option, as it makes setup/cleanup more complex, and can interfere with the test runner.

In either case, we must never modify the code under test in a way that would introduce separate branching for testing/production. E.g., "if running under test do A, otherwise do B" -- in such a case we aren't actually testing the production code but rather a different branch of it.

#### Replace Console with an abstraction

Here we introduce `IConsole` as a replacement for `System.Console`:

```cs
public interface IConsole
{
    void WriteLine(string s);
    void ReadLine(); // void is enough for this example
}

// for use in production
public class RealConsole : IConsole
{
    public void WriteLine(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s); 
    }
    public void ReadLine()
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

// for use in unit tests
public class TestConsole : IConsole
{
    public void WriteLine(string s)
    {
        Contents.Add(s);
    }
    public void ReadLine()
    {
    }

    public List<string> Contents { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

The production code will remain as in the original post, except that now it consumes `_console` as a dependency:

```cs
public class SomeProductionClass
{
    private readonly IConsole _console;

    public SomeProductionClass(IConsole console)
    {
        _console = console;
    }

    public void findOccuranceMethod()
    {
        string str = "The Haunting of Hill House!";
        _console.WriteLine("String: " + str);
        string occurString = "o";
        string replaceString = "MDDS";

        var array = str.Split(new[] { occurString }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var count = array.Length - 1;
        string result = string.Join(replaceString, array);

        _console.WriteLine("String after replacing a character: " + result);
        _console.WriteLine("Number of replaces made: " + count);
        _console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and the test code would be:

```cs
[TestMethod()]
public void findOccuranceMethodTest()
{
    // Arrange
    string expectedString = "The Haunting MDDSf Hill HMDDSuse!";
    int expectedCount = 2;
    var console = new TestConsole();
    var productionClass = new SomeProductionClass(console);

    // Act
    productionClass.findOccuranceMethod();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(3, console.Contents.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("String: The Haunting of Hill House!", console.Contents[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(
        $"String after replacing a character: {expectedString}", 
        console.Contents[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(
        $"Number of replaces made: {expectedCount}", 
        console.Contents[2]);
}
```

Comment: This is the _exact_ same answer I was planning to write. The first is a refactoring to allow for black-box tests. The second allows for white-box testing and mocking dependencies.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It throws an error in the //Act ...`findOccuranceMethod` which says that the namespace findOccuranceMethod does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Where did you declare this method, in which class and which namespace? Perhaps there is a ambigious name _findOccuranceMethod_.

Comment: @BMX: Since your code is incomplete, and flouts naming conventions at every turn, we can't know where stuff is. So you have to tweak things to fit however you've arranged them. This is part of why we ask for MCVEs. If you had one, this would be a non-issue; we could tell you exactly what to put where.

Comment: You should of course put both methods inside classes. I have updated my answer, initially I left this out for brevity.

Comment: @cHao I dont really understand what are you asking for? Seriously this is a very simple code, do I really need to post the whole class including the namespace? There is ONE method in ONE class which I want to test. Thats it!

Comment: Is there a shorter way to print out the result without using IConsole?

Comment: @BMX: Yes. If it's truly one method in one class, and one test method (in one test class?), then there is literally no reason not to post the whole thing. That would give people an existing structure to work with, so that when they go to change things, the code for those changes rather automagically gets fixed to point to the right places.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to kind of preserve the signature you could go for optional arguments:

```
    public void optionSameSignature(Action<string> log = null, Func<string> read = null)
    {
        log = log ?? Console.WriteLine;
        read = read ?? Console.ReadLine;

        string str = "The Haunting of Hill House!";
        log("String: " + str);
        string occurString = "o";
        string replaceString = "MDDS";

        var array = str.Split(new[] { occurString }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var count = array.Length - 1;
        string result = string.Join(replaceString, array);

        log("String after replacing a character: " + result);
        log("Number of replaces made: " + count);
        read();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        optionSameSignature(lines.Add, () => "");
    }
```

On a deeper level the input and output is a technical detail so ideally you would try to have your business value code without the technical detail. Something like this could be closer to your actual needs:

```
    private static void mybusinessfunction(string input, out int count, out string result)
    {
        string occurString = "o";
        string replaceString = "MDDS";

        var array = input.Split(new[] { occurString }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        count = array.Length - 1;
        result = string.Join(replaceString, array);
    }
```

Comment: a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods!

Comment: @BMX did I claim that?

Comment: The second one doesnt work because of that reason that I stated above

Comment: @BMX I see - put it into a class like "MyClass", you can reach the function without instanciating as "MyClass.mybusinessfunction".

Comment: @Johannes BMX, your question also lacks using statements, a namespace and a class. So what's your point here?

Comment: @dfhwze do you really need to see the namespace? I didn't write it for brevity.

Comment: No you are missing my point, I don't even need to see the class declaration.